# Complexe Date Query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to add a Date filter to this code:

```
var db = Database.Open("Tool") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT Nom, COUNT(Nom) FROM DTool2 AS NumberOfOrders Group by Nom ";

var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand);
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Column1", rowsPerPage:200); 
grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
```

The date would be picked from inputs (type=date)...

I know the code to add looks like this:

```
Where Date between date1 and date2
```

I just can't figure how to insert it into the code above

Can anyone help me please

Thank you

ok the code look like that now:

```
var db = Database.Open("Tool") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT Nom, COUNT(Nom) FROM DTool2 AS NumberOfOrders GROUP BY Nom";   
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand);

if(!Request.QueryString["Date1"].IsEmpty() || !Request.QueryString["Date2"].IsEmpty()) {
  var date1 = Request["Date1"];
  var date2 = Request["Date2"];
  selectCommand = "SELECT Nom, COUNT(Nom) FROM DTool2 AS NumberOfOrders WHERE Date BETWEEN " + date1  + " AND " + date2  + " GROUP BY Nom";
  selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand);
}
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Column1", rowsPerPage:200);
  grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
```

I have an error while trying to fill those two inputs:
Échec de la conversion des données. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]

Comment: Is the question how to get the values from the date inputs? You already have the correct WHERE clause, which goes right before your GROUP BY. Shouldn't your column alias come before your FROM?

Comment: What if I say it's the sub question =D

Comment: Are the dates submitted through a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where clause should be added to selectCommand query as below:

```
SELECT Nom, COUNT(Nom) FROM DTool2 AS NumberOfOrders 
WHERE Date BETWEEN date1 and date2 GROUP BY Nom
```

PFB query with input form field :

```
var selectCommand = "SELECT Nom, COUNT(Nom) FROM DTool2 AS NumberOfOrders WHERE Date BETWEEN '" + date1  + "' AND '" + date2  + '" GROUP BY Nom";
```

Comment: If I want the date1 and 2 to be picked from two input in the page... (input type=date) and those two input are named date1 et date2... What would be the command line?

Comment: @daniel-lavoie I have updated Answer. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @daniel-lavoie Does this Answer fits your requirement.

Comment: It say: The name 'date1' does not exist in the current context... Should I declare a var Date1 = the input? somehow?

Comment: Daniel - Has this Answer helped sort your problem? Please vote and mark complete/accept Answer.

Comment: I'm still working on it... there is a new error message:
convertion error: [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]

Comment: Daniel - Error you see is related to data-type mismatch. Could you attach screen shot of DTool2 table?; to understand your table definition.

Comment: The definition is nvachar (50) ans all the data look like that: 2013-11-20
The input type is filled in the same format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: I tryed on a safe copy to modify the definition to datetime instead of nvcarchar. the format change from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM... I don't have any error, the query just doesn't send me any result